# prime faces default value in selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have problem with selectonemenu component
in View i have this code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{logisticsController.selectedTrip}"  >  
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Wybierz podroz" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{logisticsController.tripList}" />  
            <p:ajax update="pojoPickList"  
                    listener="#{logisticsController.handleTripChange}" />  
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

logisticsController is SessionScoped bean and have init method:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
SelectedTrip = null ;
}
```

but every time when i refresh page selectOneMenu shows old value.
i want set default value equals null, thanks for help

Comment: might be a typo? Selected trip starts with an uppercase in your init method, but in your xhtml-code it starts with lowercase

Comment: if it's session scoped, I think @PostConstruct will be executed only once until the session expires.

Comment: You could set it to null in `handleTripChange()` after you're done with your business logic. If `selectedTrip` really needs to be nulled with every refresh try using `<p:remoteCommand>` and run it on `$(document).ready()` but better rethink your business logic.

Comment: Can you confirm whether Leo's hint helped?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, @PostConstruct annotation says to your Injection Framework (Spring or smth else) to execute this method after dependency injections are finished (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html). 

Just to simplify, we can assume that this method will execute after bean creating.

So, as it's a session scoped bean - it's created only once for user session. That's why method "public void init()" isn't called on page refresh.

There is 2 simple ways how to solve your problem:
1) If it's possible - change your SessionScoped bean to a RequestScoped, after that bean will be created on every request (on every page refresh)
2) You can just add init method invoking in your xhtml page like this:

```
...
#{logisticsController.init()}
<p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{logisticsController.selectedTrip}"  >  
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Wybierz podroz" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{logisticsController.tripList}" />  
            <p:ajax update="pojoPickList"  
                    listener="#{logisticsController.handleTripChange}" />  
</p:selectOneMenu>
...
```